# Lazy loading Angular 9/10 feature-modules without the router

Tags: angular, typescript, module, lazy-loading

I've followed the concepts in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@ebrehault_25985) in my project and also replicated in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-module-wout-router?file=src%2Fapp%2Flazy%2Flazy.module.ts) in order to successfully lazy load a *feature module* without the router and on demand. (Angular 10)

The logic line-by-line makes sense. However, both implementations do not resolve an instance of the module's component when `lazyLoad()` is called on button press and there are errors.

**app.component:**

```
public loadFeature() {
    // Dynamic import, activate code splitting and on demand loading of feature module
    import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(({ LazyFeatureModule }) => {
        // Compile the module
        this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(LazyFeatureModule).then(moduleFactory => {
            // Create a moduleRef, resolve an entry component, create the component
            const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
            const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.resolveComponent();
            const { instance } = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

            // you have to manually call ngOnChanges for dynamically created components
            instance.ngOnChanges(); // ERROR: Property 'ngOnChanges' does not exist on type 'LazyComponent'.

        });
    });
}
```

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for LazyComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: You have this error because you don't have Ivy enabled  in your stackblitz

Comment: Hey @yurzui good to see you. `Enable Ivy` is `on` actually and supposedly `on` by default in SB. That SB is Angular 10.

Comment: I guess stackblitz is not ready yet for Angular 10 since it produces code without Ivy enabled

Comment: But stackblitz does support Ivy in Angular 9. I updated your stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-module-wout-router-gvqxna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clarifying everything!